# How to find a list of non-matching records in SQL? (Having some trouble)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

**Users** - has 1 row per user with these columns:

- UserID
- LastAccessTime

This shows the last time someone used their key somewhere in the building.

**Events** - has multiple rows per user, logs every event with these columns:

- EventID
- EventTime
- UserID
- EventTypeID

This shows every instance where someone used their key.
An EventTypeID of 70 is when someone enters the building or "clocks in".

I'm trying to make a query that shows people who are using their key but did not use their key to register their entrance on a certain day.

The following will be true for users who HAVE done this properly:

- Users.LastAccessTime > '2017-02-28' (aka today's date)
- Most recent case of Events.EventTypeID = 70 will also have Events.EventTime > '2017-02-28' on the same row

But what I need is a list of the people who are not obeying the rule of the building.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: The rules are not clear. Please try to add some data sample sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables and get the UserIDs that don't have a record in the Events table meeting your rules

```
SELECT Users.userID 
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Events ON Users.userID = Events.UserID
    AND Events.EventTypeID = 70 
    AND Events.EventTime >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
WHERE EventID IS NULL 
    AND Users.LastAccessTime >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`.  I think this is the logic that you want:

Users.LastAccessTime > '2017-02-28' (aka today's date)
Most recent case of Events.EventTypeID = 70 will also have Events.EventTime > '2017-02-28' on the same row

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.LastAccessTime > cast(getdate() as date) and  -- in the building today
      not exists (select 1
                  from events e
                  where e.UserId = u.UserId and
                        e.EventTypeID = 70 and
                        e.EventTime > cast(getdate() as date)
                 );
```

This returns people who entered today but don't have an event 70 for today.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question, I think you are looking for this query:

```
select * 
from Users as u,Event as e
where u.UserID=e.UserID and 
     (Users.LastAccessTime < CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) Or 
      Events.EventTypeID <> 70 or  
      Events.EventTime < CONVERT (date, GETDATE()));
```

the first condition in where I used for join the two tables.
and the other conditions I used I opposite of what is supposed to happened with `OR` between them. so the result if there is a user who didn't obey to one or more condition he will be selected by the query.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately but probably because of my explanation. I needed all the conditions to not be met, so AND instead of OR. But thanks again, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want:

```
SELECT U.USERID FROM USERS U
LEFT JOIN EVENTS E
ON
U.USERID=E.USERID
WHERE (E.USERID IS NULL OR U.LastAccessTime <> '2017-02-28' OR E.EventTypeID <>70 OR E.EventTime <> '2017-02-28') --if any of the above condition is Violated, their ID will be dispalyed in the select clause
```

Comment: This did not work unfortunately but probably because of my explanation. I needed all the conditions to not be met, so AND instead of OR. But thank you for your time!